# Importing SCSS variables file into CSS module file

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, module

I'm trying to import `_variables.scss` file into a CSS module file to use variables to specify the colors.

`_variable.css` file:

```
$mainBlack: #000000;
```

`navigation.module.css` file:

```
@import "../../../commonStyles/_variables.scss";

.Navigation {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: $mainBlack;
}
```

Anybody knows why the color is not being imported and I can't access the `$mainBlack` color? I've tried using `@use` but this approach still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your changes on the .scss file, make sure that everything is referenced and then compile your app.scss into app.css. You will need either SASS or Grunt to compile your .scss files.